# Qt app crashes after declaring a new object

Tags: c++, qt, vlc-qt

I faced very strange problem.I am using VLCQt library and successfully run a very simple videoplayer. but when I want to add a very simple Qlabel to the main class, It crashes at this point **ui->setupUi(this)**.
the output window contains these statament:

HEAP[VideoPlayer.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00000000002F0000, 0000000000334220 )
VideoPlayer.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

SimplePlayer.h:

```
class SimplePlayer : public QMainWindow
{
     Q_OBJECT

    public:
    SimplePlayer(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~SimplePlayer();

    private:
    Ui::SimplePlayer *ui;
    VlcInstance *_instance;
    VlcMedia *_media;
    VlcMediaPlayer *_player;
    //QLabel *_lbl;//  if I declare a very simple Qlabel the app crashes

    private slots:
    void openLocal();
    void openUrl();
 };
```

SimplePlayer.cpp

```
  SimplePlayer::SimplePlayer(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
   _instance = new VlcInstance(VlcCommon::args(), this);
   _player = new VlcMediaPlayer(_instance);
   _player->setVideoWidget(ui->video);
    ui->video->setMediaPlayer(_player);
    ui->volume->setMediaPlayer(_player);
    ui->volume->setVolume(50);
    ui->seek->setMediaPlayer(_player);
   // _lbl = new QLabel;//  if I declare a very simple Qlabel the app crashes
    ...//connections

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct binaries for your compiler (and correct configuration)? Using binaries compiled for a different compiler version or mixing debug and release with Visual Studio will cause heap corruption problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never setting your `ui` class member, so you are calling `setupUi(this);` on a null pointer.

You need to either make your member a value and not a pointer:

```
private:
    Ui::SimplePlayer ui;
```

Or you need to create a SimplePlayer at the beginning of your constructor:

```
ui = new Ui::SimplePlayer();
```

Comment: thanks. the problem was fixed.  But the crash was just after declaring the new QLabel . why it was working fine before?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't crashing before you had the QLabel?
There is no way `ui->setupUi(this);` wasn't crashing your program if you left `ui` to `null`.

Comment: Yes. it worked fine before. anyway the problem was fixed. thanks a lot